# Updating BindingSource's Current property with Datagrid's SelectedItem property?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, highlight, bindingsource

Is there a way to synchronize a BindingSource's current item property with the Datagrid's selected item? For example, I click on row 10 in the Datagrid, when I press a button to invoke BindingSource.MoveNext() then setting the Datagrid.SelectedItem with BindingSource.Current; the row highlighted is row 2 instead of 11.

Am I doing this the wrong way? I simply want to datagrid to highlight the next row after an operation (such as updating the row I clicked on),  but Datagrid does not seem to offer a way to do that, and I'm left with dealing with BindingSource.

Answer (score 0):

When you click on a specific row in the `DataGridView` set the `Position` property of the `BindingSource` object to the appropriate value instead of assigning a selected row for the `DataGridView`.

Comment: Sadly, BindingSource.Current is only a getter - you can't set it.

Comment: Ah right... Well I have considered these two options, except WPF Toolkit's Datagrid control(there is no Datagridview to my knowledge) lacks the ability to show a row index integer (without using some hacks, that is), which is what Position requires. Unless you know something I don't!

Comment: Waaaaaait a minute. This was simple after all. There IS A selectedIndex function! Returns an integer too! :D

Comment: the easy way to be in sync would be my answer below. there you can easily say myview.MoveToPrevious() or myview.MoveToNext() and your selected item will do so :) no index setting at all

Answer (score 0):

if you want your datagrid and your collection in sync you have to set IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem = true for your datagrid. your collection should be of type ICollectionView or BindingListCollectionView. you can achive this with

```
this.view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(this.mysourcecollection)
```

if you do this your selecteditems is always in sync. And you can use the MoveTo -methods of your ICollectionView to step through your items.

if you have further questions, just leave some comments

EDIT:

if you use datatables as collectionsource just create a property of type BindingListCollectionView.

```
public BindingListCollectionView MyView
{ get;set;}
```

after initialize your datatable init the BindingListCollectionView in this way:

```
 this.MyView = (BindingListCollectionView )CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(this.mydatatable);
```

then just use this view as ItemsSource for your datagrid

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MyView}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="true" />
```

what you can do now is to call:

```
this.MyView.MoveCurrentToFirst();
this.MyView.MoveCurrentToLast();
this.MyView.MoveCurrentToNext();
this.MyView.MoveCurrentToPrevious();
//and some other
```

Comment: My DataGrid control on the WPF form has its DataContext set to a BindingSource, whose Datasource is set to a Datatable. Could you comment on whether your answer would be possible with this setup, I'm having some difficulty understanding it.